.NET Core Blazor, client-side, loading a small database and searching through it
I am developing a Blazor client-side application, we have a table of around 15,000 records in a SQL database.
I want to preload all the records in the database when the app starts, and then keep the records to allow the user to quickly search through the database.
The user may add records to the table, when so, I would like to refresh the cached data on the client side, and also save them on the server.
What is the best way to achieve that?
I have tried to load the data into a dictionary

And what happened when you pre-loaded your data into a dictionary?

15k records will not be fast in a client application. Look at virtualization.

Can you show the data model?

You could use the pagination to this large amount of data and it will help you with the performance and for caching you could use the IndexedDB it will help store the data in the client’s browser so every time you do not need to fetch the data from the server. And for the real-time update you could use signalr this will give you updated data if any.
